# Redcarpet don't show the pre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when I try

````
 ```ruby
 puts "hello world"
 ```
````

I get

```
<code>ruby<br> 
 print "hello world" <br></code>
```

but not get 
`<pre lang="ruby">`

the rails code

```
options = [:hard_wrap, :filter_html, :autolink, :no_intraemphasis, :fenced_code, :gh_blockcode] 
Redcarpet.new(text, *options).to_html
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: Have at least a one line gap between code block and preceding text

Link to answer: http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet?view=comments#comment_153061